# Lack of beacons events on Delphi Android

Tags: android, delphi, ibeacon-android, delphi-10.1-berlin

Beacon events in Delphi 10.1 Berlin Upd. 2 (**also tested in Tokyo**) Android apps get fired occasionally. As you can see on the image, there is no activity in 22 seconds:

[image: Android screenshot]

In order to gain the maximum activity the `OnCalcDistances` event is also trapped.

I tried to set `TBeaconManager.ScanningSleepingTime` to 0 and reduce `TBeaconnmanager.ScanningTime` to 100 with no success. BTW, the app works nicely on Windows and iOS, the maximum inactivity I receive is 2 seconds in both cases.

It is not a device problem since the 'Locate' app from Radius Networks also updates the beacons information every second.

I'm really exhausted with this bug. Any help is really appreciated.

Yo can download a small and simple demo (10.5 kb) from this link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vijghdlillp5nj7/TestBeacons.zip?dl=0

Comment: Try to force refresh by calling Beacon1.StartScan in the timer event. If you use bluetoothLE component call BluetoothLE1.DiscoverDevices(9000). I had good results refreshing every 10s, but you can try shorter values. The events that worked for me were: BeaconEnter and DiscoverLEDevice.

Comment: Hello Remy, I really appreciate your effort. Thank you ver much. BTW, your suggestion did not work (I use TBeacon class).  I have include a really simple project that shows the error just in case in any one wants to have a look. Thanks again. Regards,

Comment: Embarcadero confirms de bug, at least, on all Nexus devices. I look forward for a quick fix or a work around. Thank you all.

Comment: @iozuniga Did you solve the problem? I'm fighting the same now. :/ I have Delphi 10.4 and samsund S10

Comment: I have not tested with Delphi 10.4. To get the best results try this:
{$IF DEFINED(ANDROID)} 
    if TOSVersion.Major >= 7 then
    begin
      BeaconManager.ScanningSleepingTime := 6000;
      Beaconmanager.ScanningTime := 18000; // by default 500
    end;
{$ENDIF}